# Mongodb scala driver doesn't insertOne document

Tags: mongodb, scala, mongo-scala-driver

I try to save a document in mongodb 3.0.7 using scala 2.11.7 following the quick tour: http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-scala-driver/1.0/getting-started/quick-tour/ But I run the example and nothing happen. The database, collection and document are not created.

```
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    println("Start")
    val mongoClient: MongoClient = MongoClient()
    val database: MongoDatabase = mongoClient.getDatabase("mydb")
    val collection: MongoCollection[Document] = database.getCollection("test");
    val doc: Document = Document("_id" -> 0, "name" -> "MongoDB", "type" -> "database",
      "count" -> 1, "info" -> Document("x" -> 203, "y" -> 102))
    val observable: Observable[Completed] = collection.insertOne(doc)
    observable.subscribe(new Observer[Completed] {    
      override def onNext(result: Completed): Unit = println("Inserted")
      override def onError(e: Throwable): Unit = println("Failed")
      override def onComplete(): Unit = println("Completed")
    })

    mongoClient.close()
    println("End")
  }
```

Console:

```
Start
dic 13, 2015 3:05:16 PM com.mongodb.diagnostics.logging.JULLogger log
INFORMACIÓN: Cluster created with settings {hosts=[localhost:27017], mode=SINGLE, requiredClusterType=UNKNOWN, serverSelectionTimeout='30000 ms', maxWaitQueueSize=500}
dic 13, 2015 3:05:16 PM com.mongodb.diagnostics.logging.JULLogger log
INFORMACIÓN: Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:1, serverValue:6}] to localhost:27017
dic 13, 2015 3:05:16 PM com.mongodb.diagnostics.logging.JULLogger log
INFORMACIÓN: Monitor thread successfully connected to server with description ServerDescription{address=localhost:27017, type=STANDALONE, state=CONNECTED, ok=true, version=ServerVersion{versionList=[3, 0, 7]}, minWireVersion=0, maxWireVersion=3, electionId=null, maxDocumentSize=16777216, roundTripTimeNanos=893710}
End
```

What is missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the `mongoClient.close()` is being called before the 'Observable' is completed. I'm wondering how you could solve this with an elegant way. But regarding this is not a real applicaton and I think you are just testing some. You can put Console.readLine() before `mongoClient.close` so when you see `Inserted` you can press any key and the application will end.

```
 def main(args: Array[String]) {
    println("Start")
    val mongoClient: MongoClient = MongoClient()
    val database: MongoDatabase = mongoClient.getDatabase("mydb")
    val collection: MongoCollection[Document] = database.getCollection("test");
    val doc: Document = Document("_id" -> 0, "name" -> "MongoDB", "type" -> "database",
      "count" -> 1, "info" -> Document("x" -> 203, "y" -> 102))
    val observable: Observable[Completed] = collection.insertOne(doc)
    observable.subscribe(new Observer[Completed] {    
      override def onNext(result: Completed): Unit = println("Inserted")
      override def onError(e: Throwable): Unit = println("Failed")
      override def onComplete(): Unit = println("Completed")
    })
    scala.Console.readLine()
    mongoClient.close()
    println("End")
  }
```

Comment: Sorry, no any key. Only Enter Key.